# Pointers in ABAP (like this in java)

Tags: pointers, abap

Could anyone tell me how to define a pointer in ABAP OO?
In Java I have no problems with it, eg. `this.name` or `this.SomeMethod()`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: Hmmm, strange, there are no pointers in Java... o_O

Answer (score 2):

Probably you are asking about so called self reference.

In ABAP it is available by using keyword `me`.

Example in Java: `this.someMethod();`
Example in ABAP: `me->someMethod( ).`

Answer (score 1):

ABAP uses field symbols.  They are defined like:
FIELD-SYMBOLS:
               ,  " TYPE any.
                TYPE file_table.
If you want to dereference it, you need to do it using another field symbol like this:

```
ASSIGN str_mfrnr TO <str1>.
```

This Stores the value of str_mfrnr into the field symbol.  If this is formatted as a work area like 'wa_itab-my_column',  will now contain this string.
Next, assign the location to another FS:

```
ASSIGN (<str1>) TO <tmfrnr>.
```

now points to wa_itab-my_column.  If you perform:

```
<tmfrnr> = some_value.
```

the location pointed to by  now contains the value in some_value.
ABAP pointers are more like C pointers, you have to know whether you are referenceing the value or the location.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small report I wrote a while ago to wrap my head around it. I think this is how it works:

```
REPORT  zpointers.

* Similar to C:
***************
*  int *pointer;
*  int value = 1.
*  pointer = &value
*  int deref = *pointer

*this is the variable
DATA int TYPE i VALUE 10.
*this is the pointer, or the reference to a memory address
DATA pointer_i TYPE REF TO i.
*this is the dereferenced value, or the var that points to the
*value stored in a particular memory address
FIELD-SYMBOLS <int> TYPE i.

*the memory address of variable 'int' is now assigned to
*variable 'pointer_i'.
GET REFERENCE OF int INTO pointer_i.

*you can access the pointer by dereferencing it to a field symbol.
ASSIGN pointer_i->* TO <int>.
```